# Auto close of uibModal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use UibModal in Angular and it is not automatically closing the form.

I would like to check the state of a boolean flag and then automatically close the form if it is true.  However, before I add the check, I am just testing to see whether the auto close works and it doesn't.

The code I have so far is:

```
modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modal.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    scope: $scope,
    size: 'lg'
});

modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

modalInstance.result.then(function (form) {
    $scope.result = angular.copy(form);
}, function () {
    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.modalInstance.close($scope.form);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $scope.modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

but it never closes it until I click on the close button on the form.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: call $uibModalInstance.close(); to close it automatically

Comment: Many thanks for the super fast reply but when i try to change the modalInstance.dismiss to $uibModalInstance.close() I get the following:        VM1044 angular.min.js:92ReferenceError: $uibModalInstance is not defined

Comment: Is it OK to be calling the close straight after the open and before the result?

Comment: you have to inject $uibModalInstance  into ur controller

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/X6lkm5SBCqxEoOeuUc8A?p=preview

Comment: great help - many thanks

Comment: yo yo yo yo yo yo :)